# Command to check reconfigured kubernetes deployment is ready or not?

Tags: kubernetes

when I run `kubectl get deploy/my-deploy -o yaml > my-deployment.yaml` and modify only the container image tag, and run `kubectl apply` with the fixed file, is there a command that I can check whether the configured deployment is ready or not?

When I create a new deployment by changing both the image tag AND the deployment name, I check the new deployment’s readiness by checking the `.status.conditions[]` and selecting the `reason MinimumReplicasAvailable`. However this is not possible in the case above because the MinimumReplicasAvailable already meets (As the original one before modifying the image tag is already alive).

Any helps or suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field that indicates how many pods are updated is the `status.updatedReplicas`.

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#deploymentstatus-v1-apps), this is the meaning of that field:

> Total number of non-terminated pods targeted by this deployment that
> have the desired template spec.

This means you should be able to tell when a Deployment rollout is complete by comparing `spec.Replicas` with `status.updatedReplicas`. When they match the rollout is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the issue correctly, this command will do your job.

```
kubectl rollout status deployment/my-deploy
```

It will output you with the current deployment rollout status.

> Waiting for rollout to finish: 2 out of 3 new replicas have been
> updated...

or

> deployment "my-deploy" successfully rolled out

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Comment: Yes that's a good way if you're doing it interactively. If I got the question right he wanted a programmatic way.